# MSTest - Multiple Assertions from a list

Tags: c#, mstest

**Problem:** I'm trying to assert the listOfExpressions is correct.

I don't know the order the list will be returned in.  I'm using MSTEST / VS2010 / C#4

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetAnswersForResultIs47()
    {
        List<string> listOfExpressions = findArithmeticSymbolsInNumericOrder13579ThatGivesThisResult(47);
        foreach (string expression in listOfExpressions)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual("1*3+5*7+9", expression);
            Assert.AreEqual("-1-3*5+7*9", expression);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to sort the list before asserts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could try this...

```
[TestMethod]
        public void GetAnswersForResultIs47()
        {
            List<string> listOfExpressions = findArithmeticSymbolsInNumericOrder13579ThatGivesThisResult(47);
            Assert.AreEqual(true, listOfExpressions.Contains("1*3+5*7+9"));
            Assert.AreEqual(true, listOfExpressions.Contains("-1-3*5+7*9"));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not having a Dictionary of expected expressions and foreach expression returned by the method you check the dictionary for them to be, and be only once.

Something like this:

```
IDictionary<string, bool> CreateExpectedDictionary()
{
    IDcitionary<string, bool> expectedDictionary = new Dictionary<string, bool>();

    // Here add all the expressions you expect to be returned
    expectedDictionary.Add("1*3+5*7+9", false);
    expectedDictionary.Add("-1-3*5+7*9", false);

    return expectedDictionary ;
}

[TestMethod]
public void GetAnswersForResultIs47()
{
    List<string> listOfExpressions = findArithmeticSymbolsInNumericOrder13579ThatGivesThisResult(47);
    Dictionary<string, bool> expectedDic = CreateExpectedDictionary();

    foreach (string expression in listOfExpressions)
    {
         if(expectedDic.ContainsKey(expression))
         {
             if(expectedDic[expression])
             {
                 Assert.Fail(String.Format("The expression {0} was returned more than once.",expression));
             }

             expectedDic[expression] = true;
         }
         else
         {
             Assert.Fail(String.Format("The expression {0} was not expected", expression));  
         }
    }

    foreach(string exp in expectedDic.Keys)
    {
        if(!expectedDic[exp])
        {
            Assert.Fail(String.Format("The expression {0} is missing.", exp));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're not sure of the order, use [`CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.collectionassert.areequivalent%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

> Verifies that the specified collections are equivalent. **Two
>   collections are equivalent if they have the same elements in the same
>   quantity, but in any order. Elements are equal if their values are
>   equal, not if they refer to the same object.**

For example:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetAnswersForResultIs47()
    {
        List<string> listOfExpressions = findArithmeticSymbolsInNumericOrder13579ThatGivesThisResult(47);
        List<string> expected = new List<string> { "1*3+5*7+9", "-1-3*5+7*9" };
        CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(expected, listOfExpressions);
    }
```